# Can multiple applications access a SQLite database?

Tags: database, sqlite, connection, locking

I get into some database lock (SQLite_BUSY) troubles and I fear that SQLite will not work for me.

Basically, my setup is a cronjob which periodically calls some unspectacular Java functionality and (just new in the project) an Jetty/Jackson/Hibernate REST service via a framework called [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/). Both 'modules' need to have database access - and that maybe to the same time...

So, can multiple applications access a SQLite database, or do I need to switch to MySQL?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SQLite can handle multiple applications **reading** the db at the same time, but **not writing** to it.

From the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5):

> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time. Multiple processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But **only one process can be making changes to the database at any moment in time**, however.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) You helped me alot, though I will switch over to MySQL. It is better suited for my requirements.

Comment: What if it's using the same DB but on different tables?

Comment: @tiktak Then the _"only one process can be making changes..."_ rule I quoted above still applies - each table write will lock up the **entire** database while it's happening. SQLite is too simple to do table locks.

Comment: Just to be clear - if anyone can help. Can a separate process still read during another processes write operation? Or is the database completely locked while writing?

Comment: @ArmadilloChubbz65 In the [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) writing to the database doesn't block the readers.

Answer (score 18):

> So, can multiple applications access a SQLite database,

Yes, they can!

From [the same FAQ that linked in the `user2062950` answer](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5): "*When any process wants to write, it must lock the entire database file for the duration of its update. But that normally only takes a few milliseconds. Other processes just wait on the writer to finish then continue about their business.*".

In order to avoid the `SQLITE_BUSY` error you should specify how much a process should wait for the lock. You can do this with the [`busy_timeout`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout) pragma, using it from every process, setting it once after the database is opened.

```
PRAGMA busy_timeout = 100;
```

Note that in the [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) writing to the database doesn't block the readers, which is awesome, but the writers still need to synchronize between themselves and will do this automatically if you set the `busy_timeout` for them.

P.S. While the `busy_timeout` is the prepackaged way to implement concurrent SQLite locks, my advise would be to implement the spinning manually instead, in order to achieve more control and reliability.

There are [instances](https://gitlab.com/mcauley-cullen/sqlite-mm/-/blob/673c5501/src/sqlite.rs#L1295) when with SQLITE_BUSY the database is waiting too much.

And [blocking locks are a bad idea anyway](https://gitlab.com/mcauley-cullen/sqlite-mm/-/blob/673c5501/src/sqlite.rs#L866). Implementing a spinning lock manually in turn allows for deadlock detections, timeouts, locking dashboards.