# Detect when database is changed by an external program in C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Is it possible for my software to be notified when the third-party application makes changes to the SQLITE database that we are both connected to?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160108/can-multiple-applications-access-a-sqlite-database) only one application can write to a SQLite database at a time. I.e. you should probably have some separate synchronization.

Comment: Yes you can, the concept is called database triggers, but they are highly vendor specific, meaning you'll either have to to write them by hand or find a package for your ORM framework allowing it to generate them

Comment: SQLite isn't Access. While it's file based, like Access, it was never meant for multi-user environments. There can be only one writer and multiple readers. Even then, readers may not see the same data as a writer immediately. SQLite itself has an `update_hook` method but that's not exposed by all drivers. [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient doesn't support it yet](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13827)

Answer (score 1):

You can periodically check the [`PRAGMA data_version`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_data_version) output and compare it against the previous value returned by the pragma to see if another connection to the database has modified it in between the checks.

Quoting the documentation:

> The "PRAGMA data_version" command provides an indication that the database file has been modified. Interactive programs that hold database content in memory or that display database content on-screen can use the PRAGMA data_version command to determine if they need to flush and reload their memory or update the screen display.

> The integer values returned by two invocations of "PRAGMA data_version" from the same connection will be different if changes were committed to the database by any other connection in the interim. The "PRAGMA data_version" value is unchanged for commits made on the same database connection. The behavior of "PRAGMA data_version" is the same for all database connections, including database connections in separate processes and shared cache database connections.

> The "PRAGMA data_version" value is a local property of each database connection and so values returned by two concurrent invocations of "PRAGMA data_version" on separate database connections are often different even though the underlying database is identical. It is only meaningful to compare the "PRAGMA data_version" values returned by the same database connection at two different points in time.

Comment: This can be very expensive unless it's coupled with another notification mechanism, eg a FileSystemWatcher

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How exactly is it expensive? It's just checking a field of the database header.

Comment: To detect changes you'd have to poll it in a loop, even if there are no changes. That means opening a connection, even if there's no change. With FSW you could check `data_version` only when a file change is detected and get notified a lot faster. That won't catch *all* changes, so polling will still be required but not as frequently

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well, yes... that's kind of implied by comparing the current value to an older one (Though it doesn't *have* to be in a loop. Depends on what the program is doing).

Comment: You already have a connection to the database... don't need to open a new one. Doing so would kind of defeat the purpose, actually.

Comment: Given that no two connections can write at the same time, it seems that the third party and the OP's app only connect periodically. Otherwise they couldn't both be writers. If the app connects infrequently, just checking the data_version should be enough. If the OP wants to avoid connecting unless there's a change, checking the file's change date would be a first step, then check `data_version` to ensure there's really a change

Comment: Huh? Best sqlite workflow is to  open a connection to a database file once, and use it for the lifetime of your program. You're not constantly opening and closing a connection - at least, not if you want any kind of efficiency.

Comment: So when it matters, you periodically check the `data_version` to see if something else committed a change and refresh cached data or whatever. No need to over complicate things.